# Enable systemctl in Docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, systemctl

I am trying to create my own docker container, and custom service which I created for my work, this is my  service file
[1/1]                                                                               /etc/systemd/system/qsinavAI.service

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve Qsinav AI
After=network.target
[Service]
User=www-data
Group=www-data

WorkingDirectory=/root/AI/
Environment="PATH=/root/AI/bin"
ExecStart=/root/AI/bin/uwsgi --ini ai.ini
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and when I am trying to run  this service  I get this error

> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't
> operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

I searched a lot to find a solution but I could not, how can I enable the systemctl in docker.
this is the command that  I am using to run the container

```
docker run -dt  -p 5000:5000 --name AIPython2 --privileged   -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro --cap-add SYS_ADMIN last_python_image
```

Comment: You will need to build an image that has a distro supporting systemd. The trade off will be that the image will no doubt be overly "bloated"

Answer (score 3):

Exemple how to create image with systemd and boot like a real environment. A `Dockerfile` is required.

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN echo 'root:root' | chpasswd
RUN printf '#!/bin/sh\nexit 0' > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y systemd systemd-sysv dbus dbus-user-session
RUN printf "systemctl start systemd-logind" >> /etc/profile

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/init"]
```

`/sbin/init` is important to init systemd and enable systemctl.

Then build the system.

```
docker build -t testimage -f Dockerfile .
docker run -it --privileged --cap-add=ALL testimage
```

Comment: Well I had to restart my computer because of this... but I'm not even mad, that was really cool!

Comment: Yes if there is a bug at launch time, it's like your real pc is hanging. So be carefull. This Dockerfile works on my PC, I don't get why it doesn't work on yours. It's a simple Dockerfile.

Comment: awesome, tanks. I ran it on my vps without any problems.

Comment: I get errors running `apt update`, saying the repositories are not signed. Have you got any idea what causes this and what I can do?

Comment: @BrandonStudio I believe there is a solution on Google

Comment: @ThanhTrung there are a lot of solutions on Google, but none of them works.

Answer (score 2):

If your application is only ever run inside a container then you should create a docker-entrypoint.sh script with an "exec" at the end so that your application is run as a remapped PID 1 in the container. That way cloud systems can see if the application is alive and they can send a SIGTERM to stop the application.

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /root/AI
PATH=/root/AI/bin
exec /root/AI/bin/uwsgi --ini ai.ini
```

If your application shall be able to run in systemd environment outside of a container then you can choose to reuse the systemd descriptor. It requires an init-daemon on PID 1 and a service manager to check the "enbabled" services. One example would be the [systemctl-docker-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) script.

Comment: Thank you Guido U. Drahein! [systemctl.py](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-images/blob/master/files/docker/systemctl.py) is really useful and has been a lot of work!

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers should have an "entrypoint" command that runs in foreground to keep the container running. The basic idea behind a container is that it runs as long as the root process that started it, keeps running. Since you will issue a `systemctl start qsinavAI.service`, the command will succeed but once this command exits, the container will stop.

> By design, containers started in detached mode exit when the root process used to run the container exits, ...

See some reference about this and starting nginx service in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/).

So instead of trying to run your application as a service, you should have an entrypoint statement at the end of your `Dockerfile`. Then when you start this container with `docker run`, you can specify `-d` to run it in "detached" mode.

Example, taking the command from `ExecStart` and assuming it runs in foreground:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/root/AI/bin/uwsgi", "--ini", "ai.ini"]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply , it make sense ,  so you mean that  I have to add  ENTRYPOINT ["/root/AI/bin/uwsgi", "--ini", "ai.ini"] in my Dockerfile ?

Comment: I added the command in my docker file but the container still exit without any logs

Comment: Yes, just need to make sure the command to run application keeps running and not exit with a zero or non-zero exit code.

Comment: "So instead of trying to run your application as a service, you should have an entrypoint statement" in general this is pretty unreasonable, especially for containers that are needed explicitly as instruments to test things that run as systemd services (eg putting system service containers through a build or CI system). Its a _drastic_ limitation to be unable to just run things with systemd inside the container by default with no special alterations.